# summarize_all with "n()" function

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I'm summarizing a data frame in dplyr with the `summarize_all()` function. If I do the following:

```
summarize_all(mydf, list(mean="mean", median="median", sd="sd"))
```

I get a tibble with 3 variables for each of my original measures, all suffixed by the type (mean, median, sd). Great! But when I try to capture the within-vector n's to calculate the standard deviations myself and to make sure missing cells aren't counted...

```
summarize_all(mydf, list(mean="mean", median="median", sd="sd", n="n"))
```

...I get an error:

```
Error in (function ()  : unused argument (var_a)
```

This is not an issue with my `var_a` vector. If I remove it, I get the same error for `var_b`, etc. The `summarize_all` function is producing odd results whenever I request `n` or `n()`, or if I use `.funs()` and list the descriptives I want to compute instead.

What's going on?

Comment: Try witth the `~` `summarize_all(mydf, list(mean = ~ mean(.),  median= ~ median(.), sd= ~ sd(.)))`

Comment: Note you can also mix the tilde for `n()` and strings for other function names, so you can replace `n = "n"` with `n = ~n()` in what you have already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's giving you problems is because `n()` doesn't take any arguments, unlike `mean()` and `median()`. Use `length()` instead to get the desired effect:

```
summarize_all(mydf, list(mean="mean", median="median", sd="sd", n="length"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, we can use the `~` if we want to have finer control, i.e. adding other parameters

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
      summarise_all(list(mean = ~ mean(.), median = ~median(.), n = ~ n()))
```

However, getting the `n()` for each column is not making much sense as it would be the same.  Instead create the `n()` before doing the `summarise`

```
mtcars %>%
   group_by(n = n()) %>%
   summarise_all(list(mean = mean, median = median))
```

Otherwise, just pass the unquoted function

```
mtcars %>%
     summarise_all(list(mean = mean, median = median))
```

Comment: Thank you! The `~n()` is the simplest solution I've found after reading through a few different solutions to this.