# Error while using n() inside summarise_at()

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, summarize

While using n() within summarise_at(), I obtain this error:

```
Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Others have suggested this could be a masking issue of `dplyr` with `plyr`, two solutions are:

1. Replace `summarise_at()` with `dplyr::summarise_at()'
2. Call `detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)`

Neither have removed this error and I'm curious to understand what is causing it. Here is a reproducible example which should result in the same error:

```
Df <- data.frame(
  Condition = c(rep("No", 20), rep("Yes",20)),
  Height = c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),
  Weight = c(rep(10,5),rep(20,5),rep(30,5), rep(40,5))
)

x <- c("Height","Weight")

Df %>% 
  group_by(Condition) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(one_of(x)), c(mean = mean, sd = sd, count = n()))
```

Note:  If you remove `count = n()` the code runs without any issue

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068522/summarize-all-with-n-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is because `n()` works on the data source itself within `mutate`, `filter`, or `summarize`, so isn't a vectorized function. Just use `length` instead as the vectorized version.

```r
Df %>% 
  group_by(Condition) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(one_of(x)), c(mean = mean, sd = sd, count = length))
```

If you want to only have one count column, then:

```r
Df %>% 
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(Condition, count) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(one_of(x)), c(mean = mean, sd = sd))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, as a side question, this results in two columns, 'Height_count' and 'Weight_count', is there any way to obtain just one column called 'Count'.

Comment: A bit hacky, but don't think there is a way to do it in `summarize`, so we can just add it in a `mutate` call before and make it a group to keep it in our result. Will edit my response above to add.